# How to use different filename for Tornado logging ?

Tags: tornado

I want to write the log to today-named file 
such as :

```
2014-11-25.log   
2014-11-26.log ...
```

Any good ideas? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado just uses the standard library's logging module; there is nothing tornado-specific about it. See the standard library's documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html